# Strange behavior when registering for iOS Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

This is the code I've put in AppDelegate to register for push notifications :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
    let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    return true
}

func application(application:UIApplication!, didRegisterForUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    println("[AppDelegate][didRegisterForUserNotificationSettings]")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    println("[AppDelegate][didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError]")
    println(error)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    println("[AppDelegate][didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken]")
    println(deviceToken)
}
```

Absolutely nothing happens when I launch the app on my iPhone through Xcode 6.1.1, I don't see my `println` output but when I leave the app and go to Settings -> Notifications I find that Push Notifications are enabled for my app.

Since `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not called, I don't get the `deviceToken`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are calling `registerForRemoteNotifications()` after returning `true` from the app delegate method called when app did finish launching. Try this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
    let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications() 

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to the settings of phone -> go to general -> notification -> choose your app -> center of notification -> change it to 10! after changing it i started to get device token data!